# JS Cloning html element results in losing initial element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, splidejs

I am trying to pick out from a list of splide objects both the last element of the list (elementA ) and a specific element (with index -1, elementB ).
I want to exchange a sub-element of elementB  with a sub-element (same class name) of elementA . Unfortunately this doesn't work, because every time the subelement of elementA is removed and I can't find out why. It is correctly inserted into elementB , but is no longer in the DOM of elementA.

Below is the code:

```
const elementA = splide.Components.Slides.getAt(lastIndex);
const elementB = splide.Components.Slides.filter(slide => slide.index === -1);

const elementAContent= elementA[0].slide.querySelector('.element-container');
const elementBContent= elementB[0].slide.querySelector('.element-container');

const elementAToBeCloned = elementAContent.querySelector('.clone-element');

elementBContent.removeChild(elementBContent.firstElementChild);

elementBContent.insertBefore(elementAToBeCloned, elementBContent.firstElementChild); 
//doing so results in elementAToBeCloned to be lost within elementAContent
```

I also tried to do something with .cloneNode(true) or with replaceChild but unfortunately the behaviour is always the same.

Comment: You should include your html as well.

Comment: Where is the clone? You select the element. Selecting an element and appending it just moves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually clone anything - you just performed an `insertBefore` command on an existing element, so that element got moved. You need to call [`.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to clone elements and you need to do that before you place the cloned node at a location in the DOM.

```js
const elementToClone = document.querySelector("div");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  // Insert a newly cloned node at the end of the <body>
  document.body.insertBefore(elementToClone.cloneNode(true),document.body.lastChild);
});
```

```html
<div>Foo Bar</div>
<button type="button">Clone</button>
```

Comment: I also tried it with the cloneNode function but unfortunately i had some race conditions in it (or the slider wasnt fully mounted the time i called cloneNode). Fixing the race condition also solved my problem with ur given example. Thank you!